# Remove/Replace Unwanted Components using Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: force.com, migration-tool

I'm using Atlassian bamboo to automate deployments but there are some deployment errors like. Is there anyway to update build.xml to remove this unwanted components:

```
workflows/Question.workflow — Error: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
workflows/Reply.workflow — Error: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
workflows/SocialPost.workflow — Error: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
```

How to update my build.xml file to remove this unwanted/unsupported metadata.

**Build.xml file:**

```
<project name="Retrieve and Deploy SFDC metadata" default="deployEmptyCheckOnly" basedir=".." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
   <taskdef uri="antlib:com.salesforce"
    resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
    classpath="${basedir}/build/ant-salesforce.jar"/>

  <property file="${basedir}/build/build.properties"/>
  <property environment="env"/>

<target name="getCode">
  <echo level="info">Retrieving the server's version of code</echo>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${sfdc.retrieveTarget}"/>
  <sf:retrieve
    retrieveTarget="${basedir}/${sfdc.retrieveTarget}"
    username="${sfdc.username}"
    password="${sfdc.password}"
    serverurl="${sfdc.serverurl}"
    unpackaged="src/package.xml"/>
  <move file="${basedir}/${sfdc.retrieveTarget}" tofile="src"/>
</target>

<target name="deployCode">
  <echo level="info">Performing the deploy</echo>
  <sf:deploy
    username="${sfdc.username}"
    password="${sfdc.password}"
    serverurl="${sfdc.serverurl}"
    deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
    pollWaitMillis="${sfdc.pollWaitMillis}"
    maxPoll="${sfdc.maxPoll}"/>
</target>

<target name="deployEmptyCheckOnly">
  <echo level="info">Testing the deploy</echo>
  <sf:deploy
      checkOnly="true"
      logType="Debugonly"
      username="${sfdc.username}"
      password="${sfdc.password}"
      serverurl="${sfdc.serverurl}"
      deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
      pollWaitMillis="${sfdc.pollWaitMillis}"
      maxPoll="${sfdc.maxPoll}" 
      runAllTests="true" />
</target>
```

**Current Bamboo Plan where I want to add new task that calls a target on build.xml to remove this crap:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove references of unwanted metadata by using replaceregexp. Ie Find the characters and replace with desired value or blank. For new line characters you can use \n. 
If you do not want to deploy a particular workflow (ie: complete file) you can remove the file from the deployment director using ant delete. This will work if wild cards are used in package.xnl. IF reference to the artifact is made exclusively in package.xml , then you will need to remove that reference from package.xml as well (ie: whats defined in package.xml and files in the deployment dir need to be in synch). Removal of references within file can also be done using regexp. An example is below.

```
<examplTag>
    <someValue>Bla Bla</someValue>
</exampleTag>

<target name="remove_metdata_references">
    <replaceregexp
        match="^&lt;examplTag&gt;\n        &lt;someValue&gt;Bla Bla&lt;/someValue&gt;\n&lt;/exampleTag&gt;$"
        replace=""
        flags="gm"
        byline="false">
        <fileset                
            dir="src/workflow"
            includes="**/*.workflow" 
        />
    </replaceregexp>
```